# google drive authentication for website on dropbox

Tags: google-drive-api, dropbox

I have a simple html5 and javascript website on dropbox public folder. Can i have client side google drive authentication from that site? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: It wouldn't be secure because all the source code would be visible to an attacker.

Comment: You are using the folder as your DNS?  Then check out the Google Drive SDK for JavaScript [https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-js]-to implement it takes quite a bit more than the forum on SO provides.

Comment: @jeremyw - what exactly do you mean by folder as a DNS? I'm using the public folder to host the files, and accessing it through the public link.

Comment: I meant is there no added layer to accessing your index.html file, i.e. in Domain Name Server fashion.  The link I added above is a tutorial on how to install client side google drive authentication via javascript.

Comment: For client auth, you need to register the origin URL. So provided Dropbox gives your files a stable URL, and you register that URL in the API Console, I can't see any problem. There is a potential security issue in that somebody could take the client ID from your JS files and re-upload it to their own code on Dropbox.